# How to modify the tensor value in a frozen pb file for Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Now I have a frozen pb file of tensorflow. And I modify some values of a tensor obtained from a specified layer name `conv1/weights`:

```
 import tensorflow as tf 
 from tensorflow.core.framework import graph_pb2
 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util
 FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
 tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('input_frozen_graph_path',
                           '/tmp/model.pb', '')
 graph = tf.GraphDef()
 with tf.gfile.Open(FLAGS.input_frozen_graph_path, 'rb') as f:
     data = f.read()
     graph.ParseFromString(data)

 nodes = {node.name: index for index, node in enumerate(graph.node)}
 conv1_weights = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(graph.node[nodes["conv1/weights"]].attr['value'].tensor)
 #modify some values in conv1_weights
```

but how to write this  modified `conv1_weights` value back into the node which name is `conv1/weights` for graph.node?
anyone can give some advises?
thanks

Comment: Hey, were you able to find the solution for this one?

Comment: Hey did any of you find a solution for this?

Comment: Can you please look at the answers of this issues?               https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48879                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910187/tensorflow-how-to-change-weights-in-pb-file