# Tensorflow: how to change weights in .pb file?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to change weights in .pb file? i.e. having some new weights in numpy array assign it to loaded .pb weights and then saved .pb with modified weights.

Answer (score 0):

load the saved model with tf.keras.models.load_model('path to saved model) then load the desired weights from your weights matrix with model.set_weights. A complete answer to your question is located [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183159/how-to-set-weights-in-keras-with-a-numpy-array)

Comment: It's an answer for Keras API, but I need to work with Tensorflow 1.14 and .pb file model.